# Maui application on android - fail to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Emoji2.dll

Tags: android, maui

I run my application on Android (.net 8.0) and I get this error message.

[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Emoji2.dll

this happened on a real device and also on an Android Emulator - pixel_5

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried other apps? Does this problem also appear on other apps?